# How to get Ag Grid to display blank cell via cellRendererSelector

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to get a cell in my row/column grid to display as an empty cell or blank content given a certain case and as a CellRenderer type in another case.
Currently I am doing:

```
cellRendererSelector: function (params) {
  const exampleCheckBox = {
    component: 'exampleCheckboxCellRenderer',
    params: {values: ['true', 'false']}
  };

  if (params.data.exampleField) {
    return exampleCheckBox;
  } else {
    return null; // HERE: null sets the string value of that field as a default cell
  }
},
```

In my else case above I want to return or show an empty cell or a cell with an empty string. Returning null only returns a default basic cell with the field value as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cellRendererSelector` is a function that returns the name of the component to be used as a renderer, or null.

You could try either of these two approaches:

1. Creating a Cell Renderer that returns an empty string, e.g. `exampleEmptyRenderer`:

   ```
   if (params.data.exampleField) {
               return exampleCheckBox;
           } else {
               return exampleEmptyRenderer; 
           }
   ```
2. Inside the exampleCheckBox renderer, add logic to do the checking inside the `init` method to conditionally return what you want, as you have access to the node data:

```
ExampleCheckBoxCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');

    if (params.data.exampleField) {
    // here return your renderer
        this.eGui.innerHTML = params.value;
    } else {
    // here return empty string
        this.eGui.innerHTML = ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer but I was trying to see if there is a way Ag Grid allows us to specify blank cells since I can't edit the exampleCellRenderer class and am trying to avoid making a new CellRenderer class due to project restraints. Looks like these are the only options

Comment: These would be the only options I can think of if using Cell Renderers. Another option that might work is, in addition to the `cellRendererSelector`, you also leverage a `valueGetter` on the column. The function can check for the string value of the cell (since the `cellRendererSelector` is returning null, a string will be returned) and return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks actually the valueGetter does the job!